# Diebold-Mariano test in Stata, autocovariance denominator doubt

Tags: stata, autocorrelation, diebold-mariano-test

I'm trying to reproduce the Diebold&Mariano test available in Stata13 and I think there is an error in [the suggested implementation](http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/d/dmariano.ado).

At the bottom of the file you have:

```
// apply cross to get the covariances and scale by T
    gamma = cross(X,X) :/ strtoreal(st_local("T"))
```

The problem is that "T" is a constant equal to the length of the timeseries you use as input. The routine is using the Schwert criterion to determine the number of lags to consider. Say I have a series of 30 observations and the Schwert criterion tells me to use 8 lags. I would expect the first autocovariance to have at most "T"=7 but, in this implementation, "T" stays constant at 30.

What am I not understanding?